# how can be scrape and parse a page after post and click?

Tags: python, parsing, scrapy

I want to write a small code in python to check my parcels daily. While making a query in the web page (https://www.internationalparceltracking.com/#/search) URL doesn't change, so it is impossible to send the query by URL. I tried to use beautifulsoup and urllib but couldn't get the return.

Here, what I tried:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.internationalparceltracking.com/#/search'
html = urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

r = requests.post(url=url, data={'placeholder':'3SABC1234567890'})
print(r.text)
```

Lastly, I don't want to use selenium (like opening an extra browser) I want, the query is made in underground... 
I am waiting for your advice

Comment: use DevTools in Firefox/Chrome to see all requests from browser to server. It seems it uses JavaScript which uses URLs like `https://www.internationalparceltracking.com/api/shipment?barcode=3SABC1234567890&checkIfValid=true&country=CL&language=de` to get parcel 3SABC1234567890 to/from Chile (CL)

Comment: @klc, if you don't mind, could you mark my answer as accepted if it helped you solve the problem?

Comment: @FelizNaveedad you are right, your answer solves my problem and helped to understand.... because of i am new here and this is my first question, i forget to mark... sorry. thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went to the url you posted. I filled out some dummy data in the form, opened up the Chrome Developer Console -> Network Tab, and was able to spot an outgoing GET request:

```
curl 'https://www.internationalparceltracking.com/api/shipment?barcode=OEIOEWJOE4WO4UOI4O43U34&checkIfValid=true&country=US&language=en&postalCode=94107' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36' -H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' -H 'Referer: https://www.internationalparceltracking.com/' -H 'Cookie: ROUTEID=route.2; TIN-Language=en; Ely_vID=vk51m7caca6fj45lhcauwgj67rg1cvsj' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' --compressed
```

Given that, I think the following code below will do (no need to scrape):

```
import requests

payload = {
  'barcode': '3SABC1234567890',
  'country': 'US',
  'postalCode': 11111,
  'language': 'en',
  'checkIfValid': True
}

url = 'https://www.internationalparceltracking.com/api/shipment'
r = requests.get(url, params=payload)

print r.contents
```

Answer (score 2):

What @FelizNaveedad provided is excellent. Just to put it more clearly with this picture

[image]

You can follow this path Chrome Developer Console -> Network Tab -> XHR. and post information by hand on the webpage, and then you will see some files revealed on XHR. What you are looking for are files starting with shipment....

Click that file and you will find Query String Parameters. That is what you post to the browser and copy them into your code as parameters.

If you would like to know it more specifically, you can watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tb8gHvYlCFs&t=1302s), I find it helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at web inspector of your browser (Ctrl+shift+i on chromium for example) You can see that the webpage is making a simple ajax request to page like this:

https://www.internationalparceltracking.com/api/shipment?barcode=3SABC1234567890&checkIfValid=true&country=BS&language=en

Now just replace keyword argument values with those of your own and voila!

```
url = "https://www.internationalparceltracking.com/api/shipment?barcode={code}&checkIfValid=true&country={country}&language=en"
import requests

my_code = '12345'
my_country = 'US'
response = requests.get(url.format(code=my_code,country=my_country)
print(response.json())
```

Comment: thanks @Granitosaurus, @ FelizNaveedad and @ furas for the helpful and fast reply. Yes, it is simple and smart to detect the request URL from browser.  I tried another website (https://www.elta.gr/en-us/personal/tracktrace.aspx) but can't find the request URL in  Developer Console -> Network Tab. Where should I look?

Comment: @klc once you open the network console, you need to refresh the page so that you can see the network requests happening. At the top-left corner of the network console, there is a symbol which will clear the network console, which is helpful for readability. It seems as though the URL you want to hit is: `https://www.elta.gr/Resources/Shared/scripts/DotNetNukeAjaxShared.js?_=1561658257405`

Comment: @FelizNaveedad sorry but I cant find the request URL still :(. I understood your explanation about network concole. But unlike  www.internationalparceltracking.com, my second question about www.elta.gr, I couldnt solve the problem to sending request (post data) and parse the result! Is iit possible to explaine a bit clearly?

Comment: @klc I would recommend you ask another question, showing the steps you tried. It's not clear why the second URL I posted wouldn't work.